# Time zone not taking effective

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have windows 2012 server and IIS-8. Previously we had EST time zone on prodution sever. we have changed it to CST, however it is not taking effective. Getdate function returns time as per EST time zone. Do we need to reset the IIS to take it effective?

Comment: Have u set the culture to CST?

Comment: Where do I change the culture?

Comment: You should specify the culture in the web config.

Comment: <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US"/>
 </system.web> Change culture accordingly

Comment: You are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the timezone I cleared the cache by
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.web> <globalization culture="en-US"/> </system.web>
```

Change culture accordingly